# How do I filter resources in an Ant project generated by Maven ant:ant?

Tags: maven, ant

When I generate an Ant project with `mvn ant:ant`, the generated Ant project doesn't filter resources to replace property tokens (e.g. `${property}`).  Is there an easy way to make it do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ant plugin will generate the following files, based on your POM:

```
|-- build.xml
|-- maven-build.properties
|-- maven-build.xml
```

The resource filtering occurs within the "compile" target so you can override it's behavior by copying the target into the build.xml and changing it's behavior.

Running the Maven ANT plugin again will not over-write this customization (Only the maven-* files are regenerated).

## Example

### build.xml

Filterset is added to the copy task within the compile target:

```
<project name="maven-ant-demo" default="package" basedir=".">

  <!-- ====================================================================== -->
  <!-- Import maven-build.xml into the current project                        -->
  <!-- ====================================================================== -->

  <import file="maven-build.xml"/>

  <!-- ====================================================================== -->
  <!-- Help target                                                            -->
  <!-- ====================================================================== -->

  <target name="help">
    <echo message="Please run: $ant -projecthelp"/>
  </target>

  <!-- ====================================================================== -->
  <!-- Override target                                                        -->
  <!-- Copied from "maven-build.xml"                                          -->
  <!-- ====================================================================== -->    
  <target name="compile" depends="get-deps" description="Compile the code">
    <mkdir dir="${maven.build.outputDir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${maven.build.outputDir}" 
           nowarn="false" 
           debug="true" 
           optimize="false" 
           deprecation="true" 
           target="1.1" 
           verbose="false" 
           fork="false" 
           source="1.3">
      <src>
        <pathelement location="${maven.build.srcDir.0}"/>
      </src>
      <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
    </javac>

    <!--
    Note the filterset. This will perform resource filtering 
    -->
    <copy todir="${maven.build.outputDir}">
      <fileset dir="${maven.build.resourceDir.0}"/>
       <filterset begintoken="${" endtoken="}">
         <filter token="helloworld" value="${helloworld}"/>
       </filterset>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: This seems like it would mostly work, except that only specified properties will be filtered, rather than all system properties; therefore, I would assume a suitable workaround would be a preceding `<echoproperties destfile="${allSystemPropertiesFile}" />`, then specify `<filterset filtersFile="${allSystemPropertiesFile}" />`.

Comment: @MaxNanasy Yup, I understood the filterset limitation and your suggestion neatly solves it! Clever.